Formatting Nested Square Roots in SymPy
I'm working with sympy to obtain symbolic solutions of equation. This is my code:
import sympy as sp

# Define the symbolic variable
x = sp.symbols('x')

# Define f(x)
f = ((x**2 - 2)**2 - 2)**2 - 2

# Solve the equation f(x) = 0
solutions = sp.solve(f, x)

# Filter only the positive solutions
positive_solutions = [sol for sol in solutions if sol.is_real and sol > 0]

# Print the positive solutions
print("The positive solutions of the equation f(x) = 0 are:")
for sol in positive_solutions:
    print(sol)

I'm using SymPy to solve the equation

and I am able to obtain the positive solutions. However, the solutions are returned with nested square roots in a way that makes the inner roots appear on the left side, like this:
sqrt(2 - sqrt(2 - sqrt(2)))
sqrt(2 - sqrt(sqrt(2) + 2))
sqrt(sqrt(2 - sqrt(2)) + 2)
sqrt(sqrt(sqrt(2) + 2) + 2)

I would like the nested square roots to be formatted in a way that they all appear to the right, like this:
sqrt(2 - sqrt(2 - sqrt(2)))
sqrt(2 - sqrt(sqrt(2) + 2))
sqrt(2 + sqrt(2 - sqrt(2))) 
sqrt(2 + sqrt(sqrt(2) + 2))

Is there a way to adjust the output formatting of the solutions so that the nested square roots appear as desired? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Using your current code (applying reverse lexicographic order)
print("The positive solutions of the equation f(x) = 0 are:")
for sol in positive_solutions:    
    pretty_print(sol, order='rev-lex')

Resulting
The positive solutions of the equation f(x) = 0 are:
   ________________
  ╱       ________ 
╲╱  2 - ╲╱ 2 - √2  

   ________________
  ╱       ________ 
╲╱  2 - ╲╱ 2 + √2  

   ________________
  ╱       ________ 
╲╱  2 + ╲╱ 2 - √2  

   ________________
  ╱       ________ 
╲╱  2 + ╲╱ 2 + √2  

For further details sorting docs

The following pprints them as you desire by using the order keyword (which directs the printer in terms of how to order terms):
...
>>> pprint(positive_solutions, order='rev-lex')
⎡   ________________     ________________     ________________     ________________⎤
⎢  ╱       ________     ╱       ________     ╱       ________     ╱       ________ ⎥
⎣╲╱  2 - ╲╱ 2 - √2  , ╲╱  2 - ╲╱ 2 + √2  , ╲╱  2 + ╲╱ 2 - √2  , ╲╱  2 + ╲╱ 2 + √2  ⎦





